# Emacs stop responding on ssh after long wait

Tags: emacs, ssh

I have noticed this recently and I don't know if this an issue with arch Linux or Emacs.

If I find a file on a remote machine and then I leave it open and do whatever, when I return to that file, Emacs doesn't respond. The only solution I have found is killing Emacs and reopen it.

Is there a more human way to do this?

Comment: I guess you are using tramp for editing remote files in emacs. So which version of it and emacs. I heard that tramp in emacs 24 is much better. did you try it.?

Comment: it's quite possible that an inactive ssh session gets shutdown after a period of time.  you can test this in a shell by sshing to another machine and then leaving the terminal alone for a while.

Comment: Emacs 23.4 and yes, I am using tramp

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your ssh connection to keep alive when idle using the ServerAliveInterval configuration property.  You would put something like this in your ~/.ssh/config:

```
      Host *
           ServerAliveInterval 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
M-x tramp-cleanup-connection
```

This will re-start the connection, even if you have, say, changed networks. The only reason that I can explain that this answer is so hard to find is that it's so obvious (but only if you know. . . )